# How can I trace the source of my firebug errors?

Tags: firebug

For example my console shows the following errors

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12337149/firebug.png

How can I go about narrowing this down to a particular line of code?

Comment: Maybe use console.log() to debug.

Comment: If you are using firefox, Open up Tools >Web Developer > Web console or Error Console, They should have links to lines of code directly fromt he warnings/errors

Answer (score 1):

If u use XHR use handler.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "http://www.some.com", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
xhr.send(); 


function handler(){

    if (this.readyState == this.DONE)
    {
            if (this.status == 200 && this.responseXML != null )
            {
                var response = xhr.responseXML;

            }
            else{
                console.log("status:" + xhr.status);
                alert("xhr Errors Occured");
            }
    }
    else
        console.log("currently the application is at " + this.readyState);
}
```

and put breakpoint in Firebug inside handler.